# Set default charset in IDE and command promt

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

How to set default charset in Eclipse and NetBeans while debugging or running progrm from IDE. Function below returns default charset system is using.

```
private static String getDefaultCharSet() {
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
    String enc = writer.getEncoding();
    return enc;
}
```

How to ask java to use needed charset while class run from command prompt.

Comment: It is best to always specify the charset you want on the `OutputStreamWriter` constructor rather than rely on defaults.

Answer (score 0):

While running the program from eclipse/command line use file.encoding to set the charset.
You could pass it as argument to youy program `-Dfile.encoding=whatever` or

```
//Set it programatically
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
```